# Can an onsubmit event insert an image into the page before the page submits?

Tags: javascript, dom, asp-classic

Can an onsubmit event insert an image into the page before the page submits/transfers control to the next page?

I am using classic asp.

Comment: what would be the exact workflow ? I click SUBMIT and then an image appears and then 1 millisecond later the form is submitted ?

Answer (score 2):

Of course. The function resolves before the form is submitted.

(Although… while an img element may be inserted into the page, it might not load before the browser has gone to the next one, and even if it does, the user might not have time to see it clearly)

Comment: The image may load fast enough, and can even be pre-loaded. The advantage is that the user gets to see the image while the page loads. Posting a form may take a few seconds, as may loading the next page if it is large or complex. Most browsers keep the content of the last page until a significant part of the new page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes . You can insert the HTML code (through javascript):

```
<img src="imgsrc">
```

But it takes a little time for loading the image. The form send the user to another page in new window or in the same window? Why would you want to insert an image in the current window if the page will be replaced with the new one?

Comment: you can preload the image with js and have it in the cache for when they do hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. It would be easier (for me to write) if you used jquery:

html:

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
    <input type="text" id="someId" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and then JavaScript would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        $(this).append('<img src="someImage.jpg" alt="" />');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rYUbQ/

But like others have said it might not be loaded and displayed before the form submits so you might want to instead look in to preloading the image and then just setting it to visible before the page submits.

Comment: Hardly harder without jQuery, although it's fine if you use it anyway.

Comment: No probably not, I could just write that off the top of my head and as this question appears to be insane anyway I figured I would make it easy on myself :)

Comment: It's not that insane. It's logical that you want to give some feedback while the page is loading, especially if the resulting page loads slowly.